# Go version 1.7 for MacOS wrong version

Tags: macos, go

I just downloaded Go 1.7 for Apple OS from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.darwin-amd64.pkg).  The package downloaded successfully as `go1.7.darwin-amd64.pkg`.  I deleted my `/usr/local/go` and `/etc/paths.d/go` directories as per the standard upgrade instructions, then ran the downloaded package successfully.  The install ran fine, and all files in `/usr/local/go` are dated 8/15/16 3:55PM.

However:
Running `go version` returns: `go version go1.6 darwin/amd64`.
Running `which go` returns: `/usr/local/bin/go`, which is linked to: `../Cellar/go/1.6/bin/go`.

I'm on MacOS 10.11.6 (15G31).  I've had `Cellar` interfere with other upgrades and installs... what is the deal with Cellar??  Does the Go package installer need to know to flush the "Cellar" pre-existing contents, and relink `/usr/local/bin/go`?  How do I best clean this up - just delete the Cellar contents and relink `/usr/local/bin/go` to `/usr/local/go/bin/go`?  My $PATH is pointing to `/usr/local/go/bin`, but has `/usr/local/bin` ahead of it.

Comment: Sounds like you installed go with brew beforehand. A simple `brew update && brew upgrade go` would install 1.7 for you.

Comment: Ah!, that's what Cellar is.  Thanks @squiguy!

Answer (score 4):

`brew update && brew upgrade go`

I had a similar problem and this command, as per [squiguy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027533/go-version-1-7-for-macos-wrong-version#comment65405959_39027533), solved it for me.